# What are the effects of each difficulty mode?

Tags: the-crew

In The Crew, there are three difficulty modes as far as I can see:

- All driver help on
- Sport mode
- Hardcore mode

What are each of the different elements of "all driver help" and what state are these in when you select the "sport" or "hardcore" settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before explaining the difficulties, we have to clarify that there is a difference on what funcions are disabled while using a Steering Wheel and a Gamepad:

**Using a Gamepad:**

- **All driving help**: Steering Speed Help *ON*, Counter Steering Help *ON*, ABS *ON*, Traction Control *ON*;
- **Sport Mode**: Steering Speed Help *ON*, Counter Steering Help *ON*, ABS *ON*, Traction Control *OFF*;
- **Hardcore**: Steering Speed Help *ON*, Counter Steering Help *OFF*, ABS *ON*, Traction Control *OFF*;

**Using a Steering Wheel:** Steering Speed Help and Counter Steering Help are allways OFF, because it makes no sense on helping you to turn less your Wheel to drive on a curve section. Steering Sensitivity here should be the tunnable for you, if you have to turn a lot and it isn't confortable.

- **All driving help**: ABS *ON*, Traction Control *ON*;
- **Sport Mode**: ABS *ON*, Traction Control *OFF*;
- **Hardcore**: ABS *ON*, Traction Control *OFF*;

So, if you are a player that wants to drift, maybe "All driving help" will not fit for you since with Traction Control enabled will be way difficult to make this stunt.

**Related Stuff:**

- [A list of controller and wheel settings](http://www.reddit.com/r/The_Crew/comments/2qcoyi/a_list_of_controller_and_wheel_settings/)
- [Hands on the Wheel - The Crew updates](http://thecrew-game.ubi.com/portal/en-us/newslist/details.aspx?c=tcm:152-185457-16&ct=tcm:148-76770-32)